# php - add to array and loop variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a script that loops through a set of data, and call a function while doing so:

```
$d = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    xeon_users_rented 
    WHERE   since       <= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 14 day) 
        AND clicks_last <= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 14 day)
");
$d->execute();

$rows      = $d->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$new_array = array();

foreach ($rows as $data ) {
     $new_array[]      = $data['id'];
     $userToRecycleFor = $data['user_by'];
     $outcome          = $rentedrefs->_recycleMulti(
                            0,
                            $userToRecycleFor,
                            $new_array,
                            1
                        );
}
```

This is my function `_recycleMulti();`:

```
function _recycleMulti($ceny, $referer, $recycle_array, $free=false){
    global $dbh;
    $this->ceny['rec'] = $ceny;

    $totalrecycle = count($recycle_array);
    $koszyk       = $this->ceny['rec'] * count($recycle_array);

    $referer_sql = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    `users` 
        WHERE   `username` = :referer 
        LIMIT   1;
    ");

    $referer_sql->bindParam(':referer', $referer);

    try {
        $referer_sql->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        _OP_ERROR($e->getMessage(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    $referer_dane        = $referer_sql->fetch();
    $referer_dane_accont = $referer_dane['membership'];



    for( $i = 0; $i < count($recycle_array); $i++ ){

        # Expires
        $recycle_sql = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT  *   
            FROM    `users_rented` 
            WHERE   `id` = :id 
            LIMIT   1;
        ");

        $recycle_sql->bindParam(':id', $recycle_array[$i]);
        $recycle_sql->execute();
        $recycle = $recycle_sql->fetch();

        echo "row count:";
        echo $recycle_sql->rowCount();

        if( $recycle_sql->rowCount() == 0 ){
            return false;
        }

        if( ! $recycle_sql 
            || ( $recycle_sql->rowCount() == 0 ) 
            || $recycle['user_by'] != $referer_dane['username'] ){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now, my problem is, that it runs the function fine. Although it is ONLY the first time it's being run, it works. I have added this:

```
echo "row count:";
echo $recycle_sql->rowCount();
```

And this is the result:

```
row count:1row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0row count:0
```

As you can see, it's only the first time it's being run, there is a valid row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First impression: making a new prepared statement with an identical string on every loop iteration seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Can you check what `$recycle = $recycle_sql->fetch();` is returning?

Comment: @puelo it contains data from the 'users' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is right in the [documentation of `rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

In other words, `rowCount()` does not provide any information whether your code works.

To check if your query was successful, check the return value of `execute()` or `fetch()`, both return `false` on failure. In the latter case, make sure to compare using `===` to match the type. In addition, the functions throw exceptions with additional information, if your query fails. Check [the examples for `fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) on how to handle these exceptions.

Apart from that, you are not using the result in `$recycle` at all.

Comment: What should I use instead of rowCount() ?

Comment: Check the return codes of the functions which might lead to an error. See updated answer.